How do I configure a default SQL value for an EF Core owned entity mapped to a postgres json column?
I have the following C# entities.
class Item
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  uint ReferenceId { get; set; }
  ItemEffect[] Effects { get; set; }
}

class ItemEffect
{
  ActorAttribute Attribute { get; set; }
  int Value { get; set; }
}

enum ActorAttribute
{
  Health,
  Attack,
  // etc.
}

I have this entity mapped to the below table in EF Core 6.
CREATE TABLE "Items" (
    "id" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "referenceId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "effects" JSON NULL DEFAULT '[{attribute: 0, value: 10},{attribute: 1, value: 3}]'
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
;

In my database context, I configured it like so:
entity.Property(e => e.Effects)
    .HasColumnType("json")
    .HasColumnName("effects")
    .HasDefaultValueSql(
        "'[{\"attribute\":0,\"value\":10},{\"attribute\":1,\"value\":3}]'::json");

Now that I'm updating EF Core 8, npgsql is recommending I use owned entities and the ToJson method to map the effects JSON column to a POCO. My problem is converting the .HasDefaultValueSql call.
entity.OwnsMany(e => e.Effects, d =>
{
    d.ToJson("effects");
    // How do I get the default value in here?
});

